# Why VSCODE mess up jsx format in js file?

Tags: html, reactjs, prettier-vscode

Trying to format code with vs code prettier plugin, but cannot find valid settings in order to format it correctly.

Following this tutorial https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#overview, where I need to set React code into index.js, which ends up to format problems in vscode.

If saving the file to .jsx format then it's fine, but then I get errors in the compilation phase.

Current

```
 return <
            div >
```

Expected

```
        return <div>
```

Comment: If it's fine when you save it, why is the prettier plugin touching it during compilation? is it? something is missing in this explanation.

Comment: Got solved, check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Problem was that I had installed also another `js-html` etc formatter and it somehow took over from prettier.

So the fix was to **uninstall** that and then all worked out.